# Watir+Cucumber Connection refused

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir, watir-webdriver

Folks, I am using watir+cucumber in my tests and for each feature I am reusing the instance of the browser, that is I create the instance of `@@browser = Watir::Browser.new` and then reuse this through out my tests, I am using `watir-webdriver`, my tests where running fine till now, I just added another scenario and I consistently get the below error message:

```
Connection refused - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
      /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `initialize'
      /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `open'
      /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `connect'
      /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:53:in `timeout'
      /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:93:in `timeout'
      /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `connect'
      /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:553:in `do_start'
      /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:542:in `start'
      /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1035:in `request'
```

Comment: This is light on information. What kind of scenario did you add? does it fail at the start or when the new scenario starts? Could something else have changed that you have forgotten (such as Firefox was upgraded)? What happens if you remove the new scenario? Good luck.

Comment: It is a typical UI scenario, opens the browser and does some UI actions. It fails right at that scenario, when I remove that scenario everything works fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The scenario you added is using Net::HTTP to connect to something. This connection cannot be made. Could be anything, a typo in the URL for example. Without additional information (such as the scenario and supporting step definitions) we can't be of more help.

Comment: Show us the scenario and the step definition for the failing step.   try adding a tag to the scenario (such as @wip) so you can run it in isolation from the other scenarios which will make testing and troubleshooting it easier.

Answer (score 0):

Just create an instance variable named `@browser` in your env.rb file, and then you can access it via `@browser` in your cucumber steps.

Comment: This is good general advice, but I don't think that's the cause of his problem.

Answer (score 0):

I run today in to the same issue, and I spent *lot* of time analysing it.

It happens only with **Explorer and Chrome**.

In the end, my conclusions are as follows:

- To close the browser after Cucumber tests, I used the at_exit global hook (as recommended in http://cukes.info ).
- I saw that the also Watir-webdriver (and probably Selenium) chain the same hook to close the chomedriver.exe process (or similar for IE).
- after some trial (maybe because I have no deep experience in Ruby) I found that the **order** you use to chain to at_exit is critical.

As Exit event is signalled to webdriver, its processes are closed, but your closing routine is excuted, that tries to do the same but it finds webdriver closed so it returns an exeception and it leaves the software interface still open.
So, you have to put the code this way:

```
    AfterConfiguration do |config|
       yourCodeStartUp()                    # Put your SETUP code here including the launch of webdriver
       at_exit 
           yourCodeTearDown()               # Put your CLOSING routine here
           puts 'stopped'
       end
    end
```

This way your routine at_exit code is executed **before** the one of Webdriver and it can orderly shutdown the system.