# How to write a simple Cucumber script

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, firefox, methods, cucumber

I'm following the tutorial to run my first Cucumber script:

```
Feature: guru99 Demopage Login   
In order to Login in Demopage we have to enter login details

Scenario: 
Register On Guru99 Demopage without email
Given I am on the Guru99 homepage
When enter blank details for register
Then error email shown
```

I have the project in Idea but when I run it I get errors.

When using chrome:

```
Failed to open TCP connection to 127.0.0.1:9515 (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

I have no idea how to resolve it.

When using Firefox, the script successfully opens the browser but fails after that:

```
require 'watir'
require 'colorize'
Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path='C:\soft\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'
case ENV['BROWSER']
  when 'chrome'
    browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
  when 'firefox'
    browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
end

Given(/^I am on the Guru99 homepage$/)do
  @browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
  @browser.goto "http://demo.guru99.com"
end

When(/^enter blank details for register$/) do
  browser.text_filed(:name,"emaiid").set("")
  browser.button(:name,"btnLogin").click
end

Then(/^error email shown$/) do
  puts "Email is Required!".red
  browser.close
end
```

And returns:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `text_filed' for nil:NilClass
```

on this line:

```
browser.text_filed(:name,"emaiid").set("")
```

I found some references that I need to write a class to call a method. I tried it but didn't succeed.

Comment: "[How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)" will be useful to you. " I need to write a class to call a method. I tried it but didn't succeed." And, where is it? Why didn't it succeed? Please read "[mcve]" and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)"

Answer (score 0):

Connection refused, I'm unsure but "[Watir+Cucumber Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023273/watircucumber-connection-refused)" looks a fix.

Copy pasta:

```
AfterConfiguration do |config|
   yourCodeStartUp()                    # Put your SETUP code here including the launch of webdriver
   at_exit 
       yourCodeTearDown()               # Put your CLOSING routine here
       puts 'stopped'
   end
end
```

The code error is a typo, it should be `browser.text_field(...`

Comment: >some flag change will likely fix that
thanks fot this. gonna google
>The code error is a typo
shame on me ><

Comment: em. should I paste my scenario code into the parentheses? then what do they mean by "closing routine". I'm afraid I don't quite understand it=\

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the issue you are observing on chrome, it sounds like you need to update [`chromedriver`](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) (and make sure the exe is in PATH).  If you are running chrome v56-58, you need ChromeDriver 2.29.

Regarding the `NoMethodError: undefined method` error, you have a typo when you call the `text_field` method (i.e. `browser.text_filed`).

Comment: hi. yep, I've already corrected my typo, script is running in firefox.
regarding chrome i believe I've used 2.29 but I'll 2check. The PATH is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, I was mistaken, I had an older version of chromedriver. Now it's running in chrome as well. Thank you very much. Appreciate your time!

So, the answers are:
1. Update chromedriver.
2. Check your code for typos one more time.

Was really easy but took me a lot of time%

Comment: If the root issues were typo and config-related, it's probably best to just delete this question.  The chromedriver question has been answered numerous times.